# Backbone running a method based on a collection listener

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

In my application have the following code,

```
initialize: function() {
    Pops.Collections.TeamCollection = this.collection;
    this.collection.fetch();

    this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
},

render: function() {
    this.addAll();
    return this;
},
```

Its pretty self explanatory, fetch the collection, once it is synced with the server run the render collection. At the time of writing this sequence of code it seemed like a a good idea however it now looks like that when I save a model of the collection it runs the sync listener and runs render again. This is not the behaviour I want. Is there another listener I can use to listen for the initial fetch being complete?

Comment: u can listen to `reset` and fetch with flag `fetch({ reset: true })` but this is not 100% of initial fetch. Not sure but i would try to provide some extra flag in fetch `fetch({ initial: true })` and check it in callback  `this.collection.on('sync', function(opt) { opt.initial &&  this.render}, this);`

Comment: You could also pass the render function as the success callback to the fetch method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the backbone documentation,

> Backbone.sync is the function that Backbone calls every time it attempts to read or save a model to the server.

The event is essentially the "catch-all" for any CRUD operations communicating with the server, which is why it's being fired on saving a model. Looking deeper into the documentation gives clues as to how `.fetch()` works

> When the model data returns from the server, it uses set to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass {reset: true}, in which case the collection will be (efficiently) reset.

By revising your call to `this.collection.fetch({reset: true})`, the collection will load the data and fire a `reset` event that can be listened to instead of `sync`. This will solve your problem.